# maximum occuring character using hash table

Tags: java, string

My code is working fine and dispaly the count of maximum occuring character but not display the maximum character.
Also tell me smart way of writing code i am beginner

```
void checkMax1(String str1){
    final int hash=256;
    char max_occ=str1.charAt(0);

    int asc[]=new int[hash];
    int n=str1.length(),max_count=-1;
    char Chars[]=str1.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        asc[Chars[i]]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<hash;i++){
        if(max_count<asc[i]){
            max_count=asc[i];
            max_occ=(char)asc[i];
            System.out.println(asc[i]);
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max_count+""+max_occ);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the line saving the character to

```
    max_occ = (char) i;
```

the index is the code of the character, the value in `asc` the count for that character.

The variable names of your code are kind of hard to understand, maybe a bit better (IMHO):

```
final int MAX = 255;

int[] count = new int[MAX];
char maxChar = ...
int maxCount = -1;
```

and variables, by convention, start with lower case, Class and Interface names with upper case...

Comment: thanks bro  can i do the same without changing string to char

Comment: you can access the characters by using `str1.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need an extra if

```
if(max_count<asc[i]){
    max_count=asc[i];
    System.out.println(asc[i]);
    if(max_occ<(char)asc[i]){
    max_occ=(char)asc[i]
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can catch it in same first loop

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
  if (++asc[Chars[i]] > max_occ) {
    ++max_occ;
    max_char = Chars[i];
  }
```